# How to use a .env file while deploying it on Render

Tags: node.js, github, deployment, environment-variables, .env

How to use a .env file while deploying it on Render.

I pushed my complete source code to Github (except .env and node_modules) where I put my .env into .gitignore. On github, .env file is not there. Now how to use .env content into my project.

Answer (score 1):

You can either add secret files or individual environment variables.

Ref: This is documented in [the official documentation](https://render.com/docs/configure-environment-variables#configuring-secrets-and-other-environment-information-on-render).